# Invalid recurrence value - arrival schedule - AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W99jA.png) those are the settings for my arrival schedule. But when i try to start the simulation i always get this following error message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9beh.png)

i dont know how to fix the problem, can you help me to fix the error? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by how you setup your schedule. You chose the "Days/weeks" duration type and set it to 1 week. This requires that all entries must take exactly 1 week (i.e. from Monday 8am to Monday 8am).

For your case, switch to "Duration type: Week" as below and it will work. Check the help to understand the difference in more detail:

[image]